# xfs quota not reliable

Tags: xfs, quota

I have enabled quotas on an xfs-partition. But it seems to be broken:

```
$ echo asdf >/disk/l/data/avi/foo
-su: /disk/l/data/avi/foo: Disk quota exceeded

$ quota -f /disk/l
Disk quotas for user avi (uid x): 
 Filesystem  blocks   quota   limit   grace   files   quota   limit   grace
 /dev/md0 1801035344  3000000000 4000000000           38063       0       0
```

Any ideas why?

Edit:

grpquotas explained the problem for some users, but I still have users quota issues for other users.

```
$ touch a
touch: cannot touch `a': Disk quota exceeded
$ quota -f .
Disk quotas for user s (uid 2267): 
 Filesystem  blocks   quota   limit   grace   files   quota   limit   grace
   /dev/md0  293812  1000000000 2000000000               8       0       0
$ mount
/dev/md0 on /disk/l type xfs (rw,usrquota,grpquota)
# xfs_quota -x -c report |grep -v -- '------'
User quota on /disk/l (/dev/md0)
                           Blocks                     
User ID          Used       Soft       Hard    Warn/Grace     

Group quota on /disk/l (/dev/md0)
                           Blocks                     
Group ID         Used       Soft       Hard    Warn/Grace     
[... i.e. no groups or users over their soft limit ...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that you need to use [`xfs_quota(8)`](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/xfsquota.html) for XFS filesystems.

Alternatively, the `-F xfs` option may be necessary to `quota`, if format autodetection isn't deducing it correctly.

If neither of these are useful, can you indicate how you enabled quotas, and how you mounted this filesystem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was group quotas. The user quota was not exceeded, but the group quota was.